# ¿Como se identifican las versiones de un programa?

Tags: control-de-versiones

Todo programa tiene sus versiones : 1.02, 1.5, 4.8, etc. ¿En que se basan para dar esos números?

Comment: Me pregunto si leiste https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versi%C3%B3n_de_software o https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning ... ¿Hay algo extra, luego de leer esos artículos que estés interesado en preguntar?

Comment: Supongo que al final queda a criterio del equipo de programación la evaluación de la magnitud de los cambios.

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta incluir lo buscado/investigado.

Answer (score 2):

Si bien existen varias convenciones con distintos enfoques, una de las comunmente aceptada  es **major/minor/patch**

- Primer numero: correspondiente a la versión, cada cambio que haga incompatible hacia atrás el artefacto representa un aumento en este numero.
- Segundo número: correspondiente a cambios de gran tamaño o importancia, como pueden ser nuevos módulos del sistema o funcionalidades
- Tercer número: correspondiente a resolución de bugs principalmente.

Mas info:

[What naming convention do you use?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/what-version-naming-convention-do-you-use)
[Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con hacer incompatible hacia atrás el artefacto? ¿Podrías, por favor, poner un ejemplo?

Comment: La versión 1.0.0 podría definir un webservice con X servicios disponibles los cuales podrían cambiar en su definición o ser agregados/quitados en etapas posteriores de desarrollo. Cambios en el diseño de la base de datos también podrían representar incompatibilidades en ciertos modulos respecto a versiones anteriores.

Comment: La pregunta referida está marcada como duplicada de otra. ¿Por qué preferiste esta como referencia en lugar de la otra?

Comment: Leyendolas creo que la única explicación es que no lo noté, ya que no encuentro nada particular en el duplicado que merezca la pena referenciar o agregue valor por sobre la pregunta original. Actualizo mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que ya se ha plantado suficiente teoría por aquí, solo me limitaré a concretar un ejemplo de uso usando la metodología `MAYOR.MINOR.PATCH`

Imagina que has creado una librería que tiene implementada las siguientes funciones:

```
StackOverFlow::crearPublicacion(mensaje)
StackOverFlow::editarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::comentarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
```

Como es tu primera propuesta al mundo le bautizas como ***`Version 1.0`***

Luego de un tiempo decides que deseas anexar mas funciones, ahora tendrías algo así en total

```
StackOverFlow::crearPublicacion(mensaje)
StackOverFlow::editarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::comentarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::puntuarPublicacion(id)                     // Nueva función
```

Puesto que lo anterior fue solo una adición de una nueva característica no afecta a quienes estén usando tu librería, así que bautizas a tu nueva publicación como ***`Version 1.1`***

```
StackOverFlow::crearPublicacion(mensaje)
StackOverFlow::editarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::comentarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::puntuarPublicacion(id)
StackOverFlow::puntuarComentario(id)                      // Nueva función
StackOverFlow::publicarRespuesta(id, idPregunta)          // Nueva función
StackOverFlow::aceptarRespuesta(id)                       // Nueva función
```

Utilizas este mismo incremento de versión para todas tus publicaciones que proveen la suma de características  ***`Version 1.2`***

Ahora sucede que en algún punto, los usuarios de tu librería encuentran fallos, errores que debes corregir

```
StackOverFlow::crearPublicacion(mensaje)
StackOverFlow::editarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::comentarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::puntuarPublicacion(id)
StackOverFlow::puntuarComentario(id)                      // Función corregida
StackOverFlow::publicarRespuesta(id, idPregunta)
StackOverFlow::aceptarRespuesta(id)
```

Entonces debido a que esto no suma características sino que mas bien se atribuye como un parche a un error que tenias en la producción, le bautizas como ***`Version 1.2.1`***

Luego te diste cuenta que para anexar alguna característica o simplemente para mejorar la librería debes reestructura la sintaxis de algunas funciones

```
StackOverFlow::crearPublicacion(mensaje)
StackOverFlow::editarPublicacion(id, mensaje, idUsuario)  // Función con cambios
StackOverFlow::comentarPublicacion(id, mensaje)
StackOverFlow::puntuarPublicacion(id)
                                                          // Función eliminada            
StackOverFlow::publicarRespuesta(id, idPregunta)   
StackOverFlow::puntuarRespuesta(id, idPregunta)
StackOverFlow::aceptarRespuesta(id)                       // Nueva función
```

Sin embargo esta vez los usuarios que vienen usando tu librería encontraran que sus programas se romperán a causa de que una de tus funciones ahora exige un nuevo parámetro o simplemente implementan una función que ya eliminaste, para prevenir estos problemas tu decides bautizar la publicación como ***`Version 2.0`***, reiniciando el marcado de las secciones `MINOR` y `PATCH` y continuando el proceso llevando la misma lógica.

**En resumen:**

- **MAYOR** solo es editado cuando las nuevas características en el desarrollo a ser propuestas como publicación conllevan a que se puedan ocasionar fallos debido nuevas formas de implementar los métodos, eliminación de funciones o incluso a cambios de nombres de estas.
- **MINOR** es editado a cada publicación que exprese nuevas características, que conllevan a mejorar y ampliar tu proyecto, sin afectar las  funciones existentes.
- **PATCH** es editado en cada corrección que haces en producción, osea los cambios que realizas para enmendar errores de publicaciones anteriores.

Es un poco directo, pero espero se entienda bien.

Comment: me gusta el ejemplo práctico que has dejado.

Comment: Que bueno, espero que te sea de utilidad y a los demás.

Answer (score 0):

### Introducción al versionamiento

Pues depende principalmente del proyecto. pero en general se identifican unívocamente, es decir cada versión tiene su propio identificador que lo distingue de otros, pueden ser números, nombres, símbolos, etc.

La manera más simple de controlar las versiones es con un número incremental por cambio efectuado. Por ejemplo

`objetov1` hace referencia a la versión `1` de `objeto`
`objetov2` hace referencia a la versión `2` de `objeto`
...
`objetovi` hace referencia a la versión `iésima` de `objeto`

Este sistema de versiones basta para la mayoría de objetos, por ejemplo `imágenes` , `libros`, `documentos`, etc.

### Versionamiento semántico

No obstante en el software no basta con solo identificar una versión, necesitamos saber otras cosas ej: ¿Qué versiones son compatibles entre sí?,  ¿Qué versiones representan arreglos en el código (bugs, formato, etc)?, ¿Que versiones representan mejoras respecto a funcionalidades ?

Como puedes ver, ahora debemos tener control de 3 aspectos, por lo que representamos las versiones como

`MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`
La idea es la misma, por cada cambio se debe incrementar un número, de acuerdo a las siguientes reglas

`MAJOR` representa compatibilidad (objetos con mismo `MAJOR`, son compatibles)
`MINOR` representa cambios compatibles dentro de la `MAJOR`
`PATCH` representa arreglos en el código.

Cabe mencionar que cualquier `MAJOR.MINOR` es compatible con `MAJOR'.MINOR'` sí y sólo sí `MAJOR = MAJOR'`, y `MINOR <= MINOR'`, por ejemplo `2.3` es compatible con `2.4` pero no al contrario, `2.4` no es compatible con `2.3`.

Para más información puedes consultar el enlace al [versionamiento semántico](http://semver.org/lang/es/)

Bien, este versionamiento es útil cuando alguien más utiliza tu código como dependencia de su proyecto, hablo principalmente de código, porque originalmente se hablaba de compatibilidad en la ABI (binarios), no obstante el término se extendió a la API (interfaces). En otras palabras lo que se busca es que terceras partes puedan analizar tus cambios, y dependiendo cuales sean, migrar sin riesgos, ya que un cambio no compatible puede romper la funcionalidad de la aplicación que depende de él.

### Otros tipos de versionamiento

No obstante, el versionamiento semántico es un lastre, cuando todas las versiones son incompatibles entre sí, por lo que muchos proyectos deciden usar otro tipo de versionamiento que se adapte a ellos, un ejemplo de esto es `Mozilla` y `Chrome` que sus versionados son principalmente basados en lapsos de tiempo, 
no obstante su versionamiento es compatible con el versionamiento semántico, pero jamás veremos cambios en su `MINOR`, ellos no lo usan.

Otro ejemplo es `TeX`, que para mí es uno de los más creativos, las versiones de `TeX` son decimales del número `PI`, la última versión estable de `TeX` es `3.14159265`

### Conclusión

Cada proyecto puede elegir su propio sistema de versionamiento, por lo que la única forma de verificar compatibilidad es leyendo el `change log` (Historial de cambios), y las correctas notas del programador.

Answer (score -3):

Buenas!
cada vez que el equipo de programacion hace cambios en el programa y creen que tienen que ponerlo ya disponible para los usuarios,sacan una nueva version con los cambios realizados.
Es una forma de saber que version usar,cuanto mas mayor mas reciente es y puede que funcione mejor.
cada version que sale,van cambiando el numero de version.
El numero lo van elijiendo ellos..hay sitios que hacen v1.0,v1.1,v.1.2 ect.. o v1.0,v.2,v3.0

Comment: ¿No existe algún tipo de norma general ? Quiero decir, algo que no sea "ley" si no más bien buenas prácticas para ello.

Comment: @DanielRuiz por lo general las líneas guía del versionado las establece el equipo de desarrollo. Algunos equipos lo hacen en base a la fecha de liberación, otros incrementando de acuerdo al tipo de actualización. Por ejemplo, para cambios minúsculos por general se usa la tercera parte, para medianos, la segunda y para releases mayores la primera, siendo el formato de la versión: x.yy.zzz. PD: Se le conoce como *versionado de software*.